# Redis snapshot overloading memory

Tags: redis

I'm using redis as a client side caching mechanism.
Implemented with C# using stackexchange.redis.
I configured the snapshotting to "save 5 1" and rdbcompression is on.
The RDB mechanism loads the rdb file to memory every time it needs to append data.
The problem is when you have a fairly large RDB file and it's loaded to memory all at once. It chokes up the memory, disk and cpu for the average endpoint.

Is there a way to update the rdb file without loading the whole file to memory?
Also any other solution that lowers the load on the memory and cpu is welcome.

Comment: This seems to be entirely server-side; removing the SE.Redis tag, as it won't matter what client library you use.

Comment: @MarcGravell this seems to be entirely MSFT-fork... do you think there should be a `redis-microsoft` tag for that?

Comment: @MarcGravell I agree with Itamar. We are using the microsoft fork, would be happy if you could add the tag as I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tackled the problem by using RDB and now use AOF exclusively.
We have reduced the memory peaks by reducing the auto-aof-rewrite-percentage and also limiting the auto-aof-rewrite-min-size to the desired size.

Answer (score 3):

> The RDB mechanism loads the rdb file to memory every time it needs to append data.

This isn't what the open source Redis server does (other variants, such as the MSFT fork, may behave differently) - RDBs are created by copying the contents of the memory to disk with a forked process. The dump's file is never loaded, except when used for recovery. The increased memory usage during the save process is dependent on the amount of writes performed while the dump is undergoing because of the copy-on-write (COW) mechanism.

> Also any other solution that lowers the load on the memory and cpu is welcome.

There are several ways to tackle this, depending on your requirements and budget. These include:

- Using both RDB and AOF for data persistency, thus reducing the frequency of dumps.
- Delegating persistency to a slave instance.
- Sharding your databases and performing cascading dumps.

Comment: We are using the MSFT fork for windows. And just to be clearer we are using redis-server on the client endpoint as a caching mechanism. What I'm trying right now is to only use AOF as the persistance mechanism which seems to solve my memory pain.
However as I understand there is no way to limit the the size of the AOF file.
Is there a way to create some kind o correlation between the evicted data and the aof file. Meaning any data the was evicted using the lru mechanism should not persist on disk.
A mirror of the memory on disk that doesn't grow beyond the memory size allocated for the redis.